# Creating a Map where keys of type Generic<T> must be mapped to values of type T

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics

I have a generic class `ImmutableGeneric<T>` and a few instances of this class.

I would like to create a `Map` where each key is an instance of `ImmutableGeneric`, and a key of type `ImmutableGeneric<T>` must be associated with a value of type `T`.

```js
class ImmutableGeneric<T>{
    constructor(
        public readonly value: T
    ){}
}

const NUMBER = new ImmutableGeneric(1)
const STRING = new ImmutableGeneric('hi')


const map = new Map<ImmutableGeneric<???>,???>()

// Ok
map.set(NUMBER, 5)
map.set(STRING, 'hello')

// Wrong, there should be a warning here
map.set(NUMBER, 'clearly not a number')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Nope, but you can extend Map into your own "ImmutableGenericMap" type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to associate the two, but you can extend `Map`:

```
class ImmutableGenericMap extends Map<ImmutableGeneric<unknown>, unknown> {
    set<T>(key: ImmutableGeneric<T>, value: T) {
        return super.set(key, value);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSC28CuAXMAjEBTA4lgdlgE4CWwAPACoB8A3gLABQ0L0wA9vhCkUsCuyIAKJqzHQADkkxloRLGAAmnEAE9oANzAgkWAFzRKo1gEpaAXyaXGTDlxTQAcgFUAsgCEAogCVoAXmhCAHc4RFQMbDxCUmAhAEYTW05uaABlSm9YRxx-QKwQhGQ0TFwCYjIhAHIACxJKxJtGUEgYQvCSqPLgVzAJaCwADxQCRRgeiXI24siymPIkfABrfHYg-GoAGmgF5dX16AZmVggsFCpqIUWsVQMpiNLosnOtrR19QxMD43E5U6QifDQCBICTEAB0JxQl2uL20uhMAG5vtBrNYkvZoPBerlgqEivdOjFxkJEUwmAB6cnQADyiyYWIkENOQhcHh8WwArA0GUyoelMtktjUsCAQOx6mTGJToAB1IicADmWxQ1WIWCB1XYSBAimg6HVYGgQTAAJI+AV0FV8npvV5LLcXm8QtACiIakC7AchvwSHg+qI9SAA)

You can do the same sort of thing for the other methods as well (get, has, delete, entries, forEach).

Unfortunately, even interface merging cannot get around this, since if you try to add in an overload to account for this, only the first (original) overload will be used. You'll end up having to pass in the generics for the overload yourself... and that's not DRY at all, so I'd just stay with extending `Map`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this class reusable for other kinds of generics? For example, if I also need a Map containing `AnotherGeneric`s, do I have to copy-paste the whole class?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't think so. Even if you made a factory function, it's not possible since higher kinded types are not possible (i.e., you can't do `type T = F<X>; type Y = T<Z>;`.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks anyway.